# Error: W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

Tags: android, firebase

Getting Error

> Firebase Error: W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

While running application in Android via USB and signing using gmail id in the Android getting above error in the code. Below is the app build file and code. Please someone help. Clean and re-Build project is working fine.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.abhishek.dustbin"

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@arr'
    compile 'com.macroyau:thingspeakandroid:0.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Code:**

```
package com.example.abhishek.dustbin;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class SignInSS extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button btnSignIn;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_ss);

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                Intent graphIntent;
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    toastMessage("Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());
                    if (mEmail.getText().toString().equals("society1@gmail.com")) {
                        graphIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphDustbin.class);

                    } else {
                        graphIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphDustbin_2.class);
                    }
                    //graphIntent.putExtra("User",mEmail.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(graphIntent);
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();
                if(!email.equals("") && !pass.equals("")){
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
                }else{
                    toastMessage("You didn't fill in all the fields.");
                }
            }
        });

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.package.ACTION_LOGOUT");
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("onReceive","Logout in progress");
                //At this point you should start the login activity and finish this one
                finish();
            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a warning message, not an error.  If something doesn't work the way you expect, please edit the question to show the code and explain the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson : This is the error while running application. Updated the question

Comment: There's still no application code here that would cause a logged message at runtime.  All you're showing is information about the build.  If some code isn't working the way you expect, that needs to be illustrated here - a warning message isn't enough to work with.

Comment: @DougStevenson: Shared the code..please help

Comment: What about that code is not working the way you expect?  Please edit the question to explain what you've done to debug this.

Comment: @DougStevenson : While running application in Android via USB and signing using gmail id in the Android getting above error in the code. Below is the app build file and code. Please someone help. Clean and re-Build project is working fine.

Comment: As I said, that log message is not an error, it's just a warning.  What isn't working with your code, other than the warning message being printed to the log?

Comment: Getting this error now:   E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.abhishek.dustbin.SignInSS has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.abhishek.dustbin.SignInSS$3@7239498 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.abhishek.dustbin.SignInSS has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.abhishek.dustbin.SignInSS$3@7239498 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: Can someone please help on this?